# Issue in setting the socket server

Tags: php, sockets

I have a socket server in php server.php

```
$master  = WebSocket("localhost",800);    
$sockets = array($master);
$users   = array();
$debug   = false;

function WebSocket($address,$port)
{
    $master=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)     or die("socket_create() failed");
    socket_set_option($master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  or die("socket_option() failed");
    socket_bind($master, $address, $port)                    or die("socket_bind() failed");
    socket_listen($master,20)                                or die("socket_listen() failed");
    echo "Server Started : ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
    echo "Master socket  : ".$master."\n";
    echo "Listening on   : ".$address." port ".$port."\n\n";
    return $master;
}
```

On my command line, I did

```
sudo chmod 777 /socket/websocket/server.php
```

then

```
php -q /socket/server.php trying to bring it up.
```

then there's an error,

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [13]: Permission denied in /socket/websocket/server.php on line 60

line 60 is

```
socket_bind($master, $address, $port)                    or die("socket_bind() failed");
$master=id+4
$address=localhost
$port=800
```

I mean I already chmoded that file into 777, why still unable to bindaddress for the socket server file?

If I changed port address to 12345. then new error would say

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [48]: Address already in use in /socket/websocket/server.php on line 67

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a port number greater than 1024, on most systems ports below that require root privileges.

Comment: OK, I did changed to 12345. and now it complain "localhost" already used. unable to bind address [48]:   Address already in use in /socket/websocket/server.php on line 67

Comment: That error means that this port is in use and not available, make sure you only have one instance of your script running. You can only bind one socket to one port.